# 'Open with' icon, is this symbol actually used for it?

Tags: icons, material-design

Picking good icons is often a hard task and as much as possible I try to follow 'official' iconography. In the app I am currently working this is primarily the Material Design philosophy and when I needed an 'Open with' icon I noticed they had the following one:

> [image]

Source: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_open_with

which to me looks like a 'move' icon, rather than 'open with'. Instead the 'open in new' icon

> [image]

Source: https://design.google.com/icons/#ic_open_in_new

looks a whole lot more like what I was expecting an 'open with' icon to look like.

---

Is this just me being the odd one out or is this actually a confusing icon? And just to make this a less opinionated question, are major apps and/or system views using this icon (as that would mean users are used to it as well)?

Comment: This is a great question.  I couldn't think of a good "open with" icon, and a quick google image search didn't pop up something where I saw the obvious answer.

Answer (score -3):

Both are confusing, in the extreme. One is move, the other is scale.

I wonder if their icon for "open from" looks like a rotate icon, to complete the trifecta of transform hijacking.

Material is a panicked response to iOS 7. In deeper truth, all of Android is a panicked response to iOS.

So any guidelines or claims of "design philosophy" coming from anyone at Google should be taken with a grain of salt. Particularly Material. It's blatantly half arsed, at best. And you've done a wonderful job of pointing this out.

If you can't find an icon that's appropriate, the job of text remains. There's nothing wrong with falling back to "Open with..."

And I doubt there's anything significantly better. Everything I conceive of is going to look like a clone icon (or a clone and morph icon) as it's going to show a shape going to/into another shape.

Comment: "Material is a panicked response to iOS 7. In deeper truth, all of Android is a panicked response to iOS." Sometimes I wonder whether people are just trolling or actually believe stuff like this. To keep my faith in humanity I will just assume it's trolling.

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: Do some reading. You'll find there's more to this than a spurious claim. https://medium.com/android-news/material-design-is-different-not-better-87909af6ffe1#.azo3cysud

Comment: Linking to a post that says most designers consider MD better than iOS design and where even the author acknowledges that it's better in a lot of areas and worse in others is entirely not helping you back up your point that it's a panicked response... if anything it's kinda destroying it, after all, how could a panicked response be so different and at least of a similar level (and according to many better).

Comment: Do either of you geniuses know the difference between advertorial, editorial, propaganda and blatant advertising? Which one did you just read?

Comment: At any point in time, while you're pondering that, consider the less controversial answers in my text, and see if you have anything to say about them. That's the matter at hand, the other stuff is wisdom, and far outside your reach, and this question.